# intersectionWith([arrays], [comparator]) method, why the second param type of comparator is never

Tags: javascript, typescript, lodash

I need to take the intersection of multiple array objects, and the length of the array is uncertain. Each object needs to have the same two Keys of `name` and `type` to take the intersection. So I used lodash's intersectionWith method.

```js
const data = [
  [
    { name: 'a', type: 'string' },
    { name: 'b', type: 'number' },
    { name: 'c', type: 'date' },
  ],
  [
    { name: 'a', type: 'string' },
    { name: 'f', type: 'number' },
    { name: 'c', type: 'date' },
  ],
  [
    { name: 'a', type: 'string' },
    { name: 's', type: 'number' },
    { name: 'c', type: 'date' },
  ],
  [
    { name: 'a', type: 'string' },
    { name: 's', type: 'number' },
    { name: 'c', type: 'date' },
  ],
];


const res = intersectionWith(...data, (a, b) => {
  console.log(a, b)
  return a.name === b.name && a.type === b.type
})

console.log('res', res)
```

In this example, the running result is correct, but ts will report an error: Property 'name' does not exist on type 'never'.ts(2339)

Then I checked the function signature of the intersectionWith method in the lodash source code：

```js
interface LoDashStatic {
        /**
         * Creates an array of unique `array` values not included in the other
         * provided arrays using [`SameValueZero`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-samevaluezero)
         * for equality comparisons.
         *
         * @category Array
         * @param [values] The arrays to inspect.
         * @param [comparator] The comparator invoked per element.
         * @returns Returns the new array of filtered values.
         * @example
         *
         * var objects = [{ 'x': 1, 'y': 2 }, { 'x': 2, 'y': 1 }];
         * var others = [{ 'x': 1, 'y': 1 }, { 'x': 1, 'y': 2 }];

         * _.intersectionWith(objects, others, _.isEqual);
         * // => [{ 'x': 1, 'y': 2 }]
         */
        intersectionWith<T1, T2>(array: List<T1> | null | undefined, values: List<T2>, comparator: Comparator2<T1, T2>): T1[];
        /**
         * @see _.intersectionWith
         */
        intersectionWith<T1, T2, T3>(array: List<T1> | null | undefined, values1: List<T2>, values2: List<T3>, comparator: Comparator2<T1, T2 | T3>): T1[];
        /**
         * @see _.intersectionWith
         */
        intersectionWith<T1, T2, T3, T4>(array: List<T1> | null | undefined, values1: List<T2>, values2: List<T3>, ...values: Array<List<T4> | Comparator2<T1, T2 | T3 | T4>>): T1[];
        /**
         * @see _.intersectionWith
         */
        intersectionWith<T>(array?: List<T> | null, ...values: Array<List<T> | Comparator2<T, never>>): T[];
    }
```

I want to know why the type of the second parameter in comparator is never

Comment: Seems like you're not the first one to ask this [question](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/44669#issuecomment-902668406).